# Is it possible for a secure website to be shown as not secure only in one particular machine?

Tags: security, https

This issue was noticed in all the browsers in a macbook with macos mojave. But when we checked the same website in different macbooks with the same os, it is shown as a secure website.

Answer (score 1):

There could be few reasons which can cause this issue in that particular PC as highlighted below.

Security certificates have dependency on date and time. Hence, in case in the particular PC, if the date and time is not proper then it can cause certificates to become invalid which inturn can cause your  web browser to issue security warnings and even few of the applications might not work. It can be due to various reasons like manual time setting error or may be the NTP / time synchronization with time server has failed or CMOS battery should be replaced.

Also, the presence of outdated data or corrupt cookie can cause this issue which can be resolved by clearing the browsing data and reloading the particular website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In order for a secure website to be shown as "secure", the certificate may need to be valid and depending on the browser-specific configuration, it could be marked as invalid. You should hover the "lock" icon and see what's happening.

Scenario 0: If the specific machine has not a valid time date set on their machine, the website will be marked as insecure. (This is the most common scenario)